# Video doesn't launch and JPEG no longer displays when code added

Tags: java, android

Hi All
Real beginner here on Android. I am writing an app that displays a full screen jpg that has a file that is read that has touch areas defined on a granularity of 20 x 20 pixels. These touch areas are decoded to videos to play. The jpg and touch area decode work just fine, until I un comment out play_video(), then the emulator just displays a blank screen and hangs. The possible video numbers are 0 through 7 with 8 being used to indicate a non valid touch.

I am pulling what remains of my hair out over this.

Here is the java code

```
package org.example.video_4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class video_4 extends Activity {
    byte[] videos_to_play = new byte[960];
    boolean video_playing = false;
    int video_to_play = 8;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // now display the adBook background screen this is a full screen
        // due to the declaration in manifest.xml under activity
        // android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView jpgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jpgview);
        String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/AdBook.JPG"; //UPDATE WITH YOUR OWN JPG FILE
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);
        jpgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        // now we have to wait for a touch and then fire of the video play
        // we also return here when the video is complete so as we wait for
        // touch demand for a video to play
        set_touch_areas();

        /*******************************************************
         Problem area all works fine until I uncomment this code
         ********************************************************/

        /* play_video();*/
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int xpos, ypos;

        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        xpos = (int) event.getX() / 20;
        ypos = (int) event.getY() / 20;
        if (xpos < 0 || xpos > 39 || ypos < 0 || ypos > 23) {
            video_to_play = 8;
            return true;
        }
        video_to_play = videos_to_play[(ypos * 40) + xpos];
        return true;
    }

    public void set_touch_areas() {
        // read in the touch file
        File file = new File("/sdcard/adbook.tch");
        FileInputStream is;
        int c, v, x;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Get the size of the file
            long length = file.length();
            if (length != 960) {
                finish();
            }
            // Read in the bytes
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < videos_to_play.length && (numRead = is.read(videos_to_play, offset, videos_to_play.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }
            // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
            if (offset < videos_to_play.length) {
                finish();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // just bomb if anything is bad with the file read
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // just bomb if anything is bad with the file read
            finish();
        }
        // we have read the adbook.tch file so now decode the entries based
        // on my algorithm of invert, valid & video_num / random data
        for (c = 0; c < 960; c++) {
            v = (videos_to_play[c] & 0xc0) >> 6; // mask and align the bits for checking
            if (v == 0x02) { // inverted and video valid
                x = videos_to_play[c]; // java can only invert integer
                x = ~x; // so invert an integer, what a pain!!
                videos_to_play[c] = (byte)(x & 0x07); // mask to the valid number
            } else if (v == 0x01) { // non inverted and video valid
                videos_to_play[c] &= (byte) 0x07; // so just isolate the video number
            } else { // non valid entry who cares,  I do
                videos_to_play[c] = (byte) 0x08; // it's not valid so store the fact
            }
        }
    }

    public void play_video() {
        String myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v1.mp4";

        video_to_play = 8;
        while (true) {
            if ((video_to_play < 8) && (video_playing == false)) {
                switch (video_to_play) {
                case 0:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v0.mp4";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v1.mp4";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v2.mp4";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v3.mp4";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v4.mp4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v5.mp4";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v6.mp4";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v7.mp4";
                    break;
                default:
                    myMp4Path = "/sdcard/v4.mp4";
                    break;
                }
                video_playing = true;
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(myMp4Path);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.start();
                while (mp.isPlaying());
                video_playing = false;
                video_to_play = 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: to my knowledge u cannot play videos on the emulator. u need to have a device to test this.

Comment: When I try to play a video on the emulator using known-good code, I get no picture but the audio does play (eventually).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your play_video() will not return until the end of the video

`while (mp.isPlaying());`

yet you call this from onCreate().  onCreate runs on the UI thread and so must return very quickly or the application will be unresponsive - some of the things you have requested may not even begin to occur until after onCreate() returns.  You need to start the video and then return.  Set up other events to activate on its completion, or have a separate thread that monitors it.

Comment: This was the plan, I do not want a responsive app, the video is supposed to play until it is complete. I will re write the code to move the video out of the on create. The reading of the fileand decoding of the video to play by touch area seem to work fine.

Comment: Building a an app that is not responsive is not an option - it will trigger the application not responding dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong,

```
    video_to_play = 8;
    while (true) {
        if ((video_to_play < 8) && (video_playing == false)) {
```

`video_to_play` is always 8, so it will never play a Video other than `/sdcard/v1.mp4`

If you set this variable for testing your app, you should have removed the swith()-Statement in the posting of your Question.

Comment: Well I believe / know that the  on touch event sets video to play to a value calculated from the loaded control file byte videos_to_play[] array. Also the video never gets executed because of the is statement.

Comment: This is another bug in your code - as ckuetbach points out, it cannot execute.  Probably the hard coding of video_to_play was a testing things, though a mistaken one?